# PyTorch Embedding: Expected Long/Int indices, got FloatTensor

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Even though the input to embedding layer is type `torch.int64` I am still getting the error `expected argument of scalar type long or int, but got torch.FloatTensor`.

```
for epoch in range(inital_epoch, config[‘number_epochs’]):
    model.train()
    batch_iterator = tqdm(train_dataloader, desc = f’Processing epoch {epoch:02d}')
    for batch in batch_iterator:
        encoder_input = batch[‘encoder_input’].to(device) # (batch_size, context_len)
        decoder_input = batch[‘decoder_input’].to(device) # (batch_size, context_len)
        encoder_mask = batch[‘encoder_mask’].to(device) # (batch_size, 1, context_len)
        decoder_mask = batch[‘decoder_mask’].to(device) # (batch_size, context_len, context_len)

        print(f"encoder_input dtype: {encoder_input.dtype}")
        print(f"encoder_input shape: {encoder_input.shape}")

        encoder_output = model.encoder(encoder_input, encoder_mask)
```

In above code, I have added print statement to inspect the dtype and shape of the encoder_input.

When I execute the file I’m getting below error:

```
Using device cpu
Processing epoch 00:   0%|                                                                                                       | 0/12771 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
encoder_input dtype: torch.int64
encoder_input shape: torch.Size([8, 440])
Processing epoch 00:   0%|                                                                                                       | 0/12771 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Fahad\College\BE\Project\MT using Transformers\train.py", line 137, in <module>
    train_model(config)
  File "E:\Fahad\College\BE\Project\MT using Transformers\train.py", line 107, in train_model
    encoder_output = model.encoder(encoder_input, encoder_mask) # (batch_size, context_len, embedding_size)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Fahad\College\BE\Project\MT using Transformers\model.py", line 246, in encoder
    return self.encoder(src, src_mask)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Fahad\College\BE\Project\MT using Transformers\model.py", line 240, in encoder
    src = self.input_embedding(src)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Fahad\College\BE\Project\MT using Transformers\model.py", line 18, in forward
    return self.embedding(x) * math.sqrt(self.embedding_dim)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py", line 163, in forward
    return F.embedding(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2237, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have one of the following scalar types: Long, Int; but got torch.FloatTensor instead (while checking arguments for embedding)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know where the issue lies unless you share your "model.py" file. But from my experence, you could try tracking all tensor operations inside the encoder's `forward` function of your model.Tensor datatypes can be converted automatically in most tensor operations. I bet `src` tensor did some calculations with a float tensor unexpectedly in your case.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I made a silly mistake while defining the model and figured out using some print statements. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a line code before forward:

```
x = x.long()
```

But you best to check the data of x, make sure of x's dtype

Answer (score 1):

The Embedding layer receives a tensor of int/long as input:

```
encoder_input = encoder_input.to(torch.long)
```